# getting and posting method in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an application on wich I using "post" method to send some data to third party application.Then, third party application running some java with my posted data and then it provides me an html page.Do I have any possibility programatically to review the source code of this rendered page to find some data on it?

```
NameValueCollection data = new NameValueCollection();
data.Add("v1", "val1");
data.Add("v2", "val2");
HttpClass.RedirectAndPOST(this.Page, "http://DestUrl/Default.aspx", data);



 public static void RedirectAndPOST(Page page, string destinationUrl, 
                               NameValueCollection data)
 {
 //Prepare the Posting form
 string strForm = PreparePOSTForm(destinationUrl, data);
  //Add a literal control the specified page holding 
 //the Post Form, this is to submit the Posting form with the request.
  page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(strForm));
  }
  public static void RedirectAndPOST(Page page, string destinationUrl, 
                               NameValueCollection data)
  {
  //Prepare the Posting form
  string strForm = PreparePOSTForm(destinationUrl, data);
  //Add a literal control the specified page holding 
  //the Post Form, this is to submit the Posting form with the request.
  page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(strForm));
  }

 private static String PreparePOSTForm(string url, NameValueCollection data)
  {
 //Set a name for the form
 string formID = "PostForm";
 //Build the form using the specified data to be posted.
 StringBuilder strForm = new StringBuilder();
 strForm.Append("<form id=\"" + formID + "\" name=\"" + 
               formID + "\" action=\"" + url + 
               "\" method=\"POST\">");

 foreach (string key in data)
 {
    strForm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + key + 
                    "\" value=\"" + data[key] + "\">");
 }

 strForm.Append("</form>");
 //Build the JavaScript which will do the Posting operation.
 StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();
 strScript.Append("<script language="'javascript'">");
 strScript.Append("var v" + formID + " = document." + 
                 formID + ";");
 strScript.Append("v" + formID + ".submit();");
 strScript.Append("</script>");
 //Return the form and the script concatenated.
 //(The order is important, Form then JavaScript)
 return strForm.ToString() + strScript.ToString();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect to a page that just triggers a post seems like a lot of unnecessary work, and prevents you from examining the returned source code.

I would recommend using the [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) and [WebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.aspx) classes.  In your code, you create a WebRequest using the URL and data you want to POST.  You then submit it as a POST, and get the response object.  You can then examine the response content (source code) before writing it back to your client.